# How to create add-on for Mozilla Thunderbird desktop app?

Tags: mozilla, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am beginner to Mozilla Addons Development. I want to create add-on Mozilla Thunderbird desktop app. I researched how to create it but i found only browser extension.

Where should I start?

Thanks. I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for add-ons development has been updated very recently, you can find it here:

https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons

I'd suggest subscribing to this mailing list and announcing what you do, it's also a useful place to ask add-on development questions and make suggestions about it:

https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/tb-planning